# Point top-level domains to individual records in a rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dns, wildcard-subdomain, tld

Is there a way to point top-level domains to individual records in a rails app - similar to subdomains.
kinda like http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-mu-domain-mapping/

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at constraints and the [`request object`](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object):

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object

```
match '/' => {:controller => "mycontroller", :action => "show", :id => "1"}, 
  :constraints => { :domain => "mydomain.com" }
```

(Remove the line-break if this doesn't work)